# coloring, make cell style normal and merging specific range in excel vb 2019

Tags: visual-studio

can some one make this code short
For j = 1 To 7
formatb = oS.Range("b" & Lr + j)
formatb.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightYellow)
formatb = oS.Range("d" & Lr + j)
formatb.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightYellow)
formatb = oS.Range("c" & Lr + j)
formatb.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightYellow)

```
        formatRange = oS.Range("b" & Lr + j)
        formatRange.BorderAround(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlMedium, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic)
        formatRange = oS.Range("c" & Lr + j)
        formatRange.BorderAround(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlMedium, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic)
        formatRange = oS.Range("d" & Lr + j)
        formatRange.BorderAround(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlMedium, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic)

        oS.Range("a" & Lr + j).Style = "Normal"
        oS.Range("e" & Lr + j).Style = "Normal"
        oS.Range("f" & Lr + j).Style = "Normal"
        oS.Range("g" & Lr + j).Style = "Normal"
        oS.Range("h" & Lr + j).Style = "Normal"
        oS.Range("i" & Lr + j).Style = "Normal"
        oS.Range("j" & Lr + j).Style = "Normal"
        oS.Range("k" & Lr + j).Style = "Normal"
        oS.Range("l" & Lr + j).Style = "Normal"
        oS.Range("m" & Lr + j).Style = "Normal"
        oS.Range("n" & Lr + j).Style = "Normal"
        oS.Range("o" & Lr + j).Style = "Normal"

        formatRange = oS.Range("a" & Lr + j)
        formatRange.Merge()
        formatRange = oS.Range("e" & Lr + j)
        formatRange.Merge()
        formatRange = oS.Range("f" & Lr + j)
        formatRange.Merge()
        formatRange = oS.Range("g" & Lr + j)
        formatRange.Merge()
        formatRange = oS.Range("h" & Lr + j)
        formatRange.Merge()
        formatRange = oS.Range("i" & Lr + j)
        formatRange.Merge()
        formatRange = oS.Range("j" & Lr + j)
        formatRange.Merge()
        formatRange = oS.Range("k" & Lr + j)
        formatRange.Merge()
        formatRange = oS.Range("l" & Lr + j)
        formatRange.Merge()
        formatRange = oS.Range("m" & Lr + j)
        formatRange.Merge()
        formatRange = oS.Range("n" & Lr + j)
        formatRange.Merge()
        formatRange = oS.Range("o" & Lr + j)
        formatRange.Merge()
    Next j
```